# Creating an array of hashes is showing slow performance, how can this be improved?

Tags: performance, perl

Running my script through Devel::NYTProf showed that the following portion of code took up the vast majority of running time. The function creates a hash that's easier to work with, and that hash gets pushed into an array. I'm wondering how this can be done without taking as long as it does.

From Devel::NYTProf:

```
# Statements | Time on line | Calls | Time in sub
21092   16.4s   21092   273s     push( @events, { create_events_hash($1, $2, $j, @eventHash) } );
# spent 273s making 21092 calls to Parser::create_events_hash, avg 12.9ms/call

# ...                   

# spent 273s (268+4.95) within Parser::create_events_hash which was called 21092 times, 
    avg 12.9ms/call: # 21092 times (268s+4.95s) by 
    Parser::findNewMessages at line 86, avg 12.9ms/call  
# Statements | Time on line 

sub create_events_hash {
    21092   159s            my ( $dateIndex, $msgIDIndex, $eventHashIndex, @eventHash ) = @_;                       

    21092   81.8ms          my %holder;
    21092   137ms           $holder{ID} = $eventHashIndex;
    21092   190ms           $holder{msgDate} = $dateIndex;
    21092   243ms           $holder{ReceivedAt} = $eventHash[$eventHashIndex]{ReceivedAt};
    21092   181ms           $holder{msgID} = $msgIDIndex;
    21092   193ms           $holder{FromHost} = $eventHash[$eventHashIndex]{FromHost};
    21092   187ms           $holder{Priority} = $eventHash[$eventHashIndex]{Priority};

    21092   97.6s           return %holder;
                    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, I'd send @eventhash as reference.

```
push(@events, {create_events_hash($1, $2, $j, \@eventHash)});
```

It is more effecient this way as it won't make a copy of the array.

Comment: Why not pass \$eventHash[$j] ?

Comment: This did it, script went from taking 5-6 minutes to 30 seconds. Thanks!

Comment: @LenJaffe He needs $j in his sub regardless of using it as an index. So either way, he has to pass on the value of $j. However, passing reference to only one item in array makes for a neater assignment in the sub. I agree. Not sure if it will make any difference in the speed.

Comment: @Hameed - if the optimizer is msart enough to optimize away the array lookups, then it won't, but it might make for more "semantically correct: code, and probably more readable. Since create_events_hash() only operated on one element of the array, passing that element in is semantically valid, and as you've noted, it makes the assignments cleaner, which helps later, when you have to read it again to modify it, and despite having written it six months ago, it looks like somebody else's code.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you can't really squeeze very much time out of a bunch of assignment statements.

You may have to examine your algorithm, why are you calling that sub 21k times?

You already have an array of hashes. Maybe you're iterating in a really inefficient way.

Plus you're passing a hash out to the function, instead of a hash ref.  So try passing a reference in, as @Hameed suggested, and try passing a reference out as well, and see what that does.

Passing the reference out will probably have the least impact on your code, and then you can see what kind of impact passing refs vs objects has on the runtime. But I will agree with Hameed - the large array you're passing in will take more time to copy onto the stack then the small hash that you are returning.

Comment: The sub is being called 21k times because this part of the script is checking rows of a MySQL query for certain stuff, the matching results are used later on. It was indeed passing the large array that was the root problem.

Comment: Nu? What kind of time improvements did you see?

Comment: ...and I'm glad it turned out to be that simple.

Comment: It was taking ~5-6 minutes previously, now it's ~30 seconds. The @eventHash has some 99k MySQL query results, so I suppose it should've been obvious why it was slow. I'm glad it was this simple too!